# Почему не работает state.set_state() в Aiogram3?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Когда я нажимаю на "✅ Согласен", callback работает (Выводит сообщение: "Хорошо, добавляем вас в нашу базу данных, ожидайте..."), но почему-то не переходит состояние в `RegistrationState.TelegramID`, из-за чего дальнейшие действия не происходит. Я думаю, что всё из-за callback_query, но не уверен в этом.

Вот мой код:

```py
bot = Bot("XXXXXXXXXX")
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(storage=storage)
router = Router()
dp.include_router(router)
database: Database = None

class RegistrationState(StatesGroup):
    TelegramID = State()
    Username = State()
    PhotoURL = State()
    FullName = State()

# ...

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):

    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(InlineKeyboardButton(
        text="✅ Согласен",
        callback_data="agree")
    )

    with open("PRIVACY.md", encoding="UTF-8") as privacy:
        await msg.answer(privacy.read(), parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=builder.as_markup())


@router.callback_query(lambda c: c.data == 'agree')
async def agree_callback(callback_query: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback_query.answer("Хорошо, добавляем вас в нашу базу данных, ожидайте...")
    await state.set_state(RegistrationState.TelegramID)


@router.message(RegistrationState.TelegramID)
async def process_telegram_id(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    global database
    #...

    await msg.answer(f"Добро пожаловать, {data['FullName']}! Чтобы начать поиск объявлений, нажмите на 'Поиск'. Если вы хотите продать своего щенка, нажмите на режим 'Бизнеса'")
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: А почему ты решил, что не устанавливается состояние в коллбэке?

Comment: @CausonQ Ну потому что иначе бы вывел сообщение "Добро пожаловать...", но этого не происходит, выводит только "Хорошо, добавляем вас в нашу базу данных, ожидайте...". Если я правильно понял твой вопрос.

Comment: А ты отправляешь какое-нибудь сообщение боту, дл того, что бы он вывел Добро пожаловать...?

Comment: @CausonQ Нет. process_telegram_id сразу добавляет данные пользователя (фото профиля, ID telegram, имя и фамилия телеграмма) в базу данных

Comment: А данные в БД появляются?

Comment: @CausonQ нет, вообще, я в начале поставил print("...") в process_telegram_id, для того, чтобы понять, работает ли вообще состояние. Я нажимаю на "✅ Согласен" и ничего не выводит в консоли, значит что-то не так с состоянием, наверное...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты не записываешь в стейт ничего, поэтому там ничего и нет.

Обработка в твоем случае происходит следующим образом:
При нажатии на кнопку старт бот отправляет сообщение с инлайн кнопкой. При нажатии на кнопку - срабатывает коллбэк и устанавливается стейт. Дальнейшая обработка останавливается.

Следующий хендлер сработает только при отправке боту чего-либо: сообщения, картинки, видео и тд. Потому что ты составил хендлер так:

```
@router.message(RegistrationState.TelegramID)
```

Comment: Тю, только сейчас до меня дошло . Спасибо, да, он всё это время ожидал отправки, тогда уже другой вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы не ждал, ну это уже наверное сам решу 
А так, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

если вы хотите сделать хендлере проверку на состояние то нужно указывать в хендлере RegistrationState.TelegramID.filter() а не просто передать RegistrationState.TelegramID

@router.message(RegistrationState.TelegramID.filter())
async def process_telegram_id(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
global database
#...*текст курсивом*

```
await msg.answer(f"Добро пожаловать, {data['FullName']}! Чтобы начать поиск объявлений, нажмите на 'Поиск'. Если вы хотите продать своего щенка, нажмите на режим 'Бизнеса'")
await state.finish()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но выводит ошибку: AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'filter'
Такой функции нет, может не ту библиотеку подключаю "from aiogram.filters.state import StatesGroup, State"?

Comment: забыл сказать что нужно обернуть в StateFilter() вот рабочий обработчик: 

from aiogram.filters import Command, StateFilter
@router.message(StateFilter(RegistrationState.TelegramID.filter()))

Comment: Мда 
Я попробовал, прикол в том, что нет такой функции filter(), я стал использовать StateFilter с filter() и без, с filter() выводит ошибку, а без него ничего не выводит. Жесть

Comment: тут тебе объяснят, прям с примером

https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/fsm/